# How to use python variable in os.system?

Tags: python

I am creating small console script in python, and I will like to put cowsay command in it, but cow says name of the variable, where the string is, not the string inside the variable.
How I can get the cow to say string inside the variable?

```
if (command == 'cow'):
    word = raw_input('What does the cow say?  ')
    os.system('cowsay word')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

lazy solution is to simply concatenate the word:

```
>>> import os
>>> word="moo"
>>> os.system('cowsay ' + word)
 _____ 
< moo >
 ----- 
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
0
```

BUT you should not do this.
What if the user inputs `moo; rm -rf /`? guess what will happen.
Also, `word="$(cat /etc/passwd)"` and `word="$aliases"` or words with backticks will yield non-expected results.

You should use the [Subprocess module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), which takes care of escaping shell args and constructing the call:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.Popen(['cowsay', word])
<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7fe8c7656c18>
>>>  _____ 
< moo >
 ----- 
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

Use `.communicate()` for simple invocations, as described in the docs or as in the example below.
And now you don't have to worry about injections:

```
>>> word="$(cat /etc/passwd)"
>>> stdout, stderr = subprocess.Popen(
                     ['cowsay', word]).communicate()
 ____________________ 
< $(cat /etc/passwd) >
 -------------------- 
        \   ^__^
         \  (oo)\_______
            (__)\       )\/\
                ||----w |
                ||     ||
```

Comment: Thanks, but what does the "<subprocess.Popen object at 0x7fe8c7656c18>" line do?

Comment: that's just the subprocess object returned by `Popen`. You can bind it to a variable and communicate with it.

Comment: So I bind it into variable and I can communicate with it how? What I can do when I communicate with it? (And yes I am newbie on programming)

Comment: take a look at the docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html You can send data to it's stdin, for example.

Comment: You should prefer `subprocess.run()` and friends over bare `subprocess.Popen()` (`subprocess.check_call()` etc in Python 2). The basic `Popen` constructor is useful if you need to manage the process yourself, but you don't want to when you don't have to.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `format` to construct the string

```
os.system('cowsay {}'.format(word))
```

Or simple string concatenation

```
os.system('cowsay ' + word)
```

But I prefer the former, especially if the string get more complicated.